# .htaccess rewrite with slash

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I'm trying to URL rewrite using `.htaccess`

from
`example.com/daily.php` to `example.com/daily` (and `example.com/daily/`)

with the following code:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule daily/$ daily.php
```

however:

- `example.com/daily/` = ok
- `example.com/daily`  = not ok

Comment: "from `example.com/daily.php` to `example.com/daily` (and `mysite.com/daily/`)" - You mean the other way round?!

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> RewriteRule daily/$ daily.php
> ```

In the above `RewriteRule` directive, `daily/$` is a regular expression (regex) that matches against the URL-path in the request. This regex contains a trailing slash (`/`), so this will clearly not match a URL that does not end in a slash.

If you want to match both `/daily/` and `/daily` (although I would not recommend this - see note below) then you need to make the trailing slash *optional* in the regex. You make this character optional by following it with `?` (question mark). For example:

```
RewriteRule ^daily/?$ daily.php [L]
```

I've also included a start-of-string anchor `^`, so it only matches `/daily` and not `/<anything>daily`. You will probably want the `L` (`last`) flag, if you plan on adding any more directives.

*Aside*: If you allow both `/daily/` and `/daily`, which are technically two different URLs then you potentially have "duplicate content". You should choose one or the other as the canonical URL. And optionally route the non-canonical version to the other.